# How to transform 2-levels-deep foreach loop to LINQ expression to produce Dictionary<string,SomeList<Item>>?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

How do I transform this function:

```
void MyFunc () {
    foreach (var k in problems.Keys)
    {
        var list = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>();
        listViewItems.Add(k, list);
        foreach (var i in problems[k].Items)
        {
            list.Add(new ListViewItem
            {
                Token = i.Token,
                IsFatalError = i.IsFatal,
                Checked = false,
                Line = i.Token.Position.Line,
                Description = i.Description,
                BackgroundBrush = i.IsFatal ? Brushes.Red : null
            });
        }
    }
}
```

to LINQ query syntax ? here are the types and variables:

```
public class ProblemsList {
    public class Problem {
        public IToken Token { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsFatal { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Problem> Items { get { return problems; } }
}

public class ListViewItem {
    public bool IsFatalError { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public int Line { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Brush BackgroundBrush { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, ProblemsList> problems;

Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>> listViewItems
    = new Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>>();
```

Comment: what is `problems.Keys`? (assuming that `problems` is of type `ProblemsList`)

Comment: @w0lf: sorry, fixed this. it's actually: `Dictionary<string, ProblemsList> problems`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it (using chained methods syntax):

```
listViewItems = problems.ToDictionary(
    p => p.Key,
    p => new ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>(
        p.Value.Items.Select(
            i => new ListViewItem
                {
                    Token = i.Token,
                    IsFatalError = i.IsFatal,
                    Checked = false,
                    Line = i.Token.Position.Line,
                    Description = i.Description,
                    BackgroundBrush = i.IsFatal ? Brushes.Red : null
                }
            )
        )
    );
```

---

#### Update

A version that uses query syntax as much as possible:

```
listViewItems = (
        from p in problems
        select new
            {
                Key = p.Key,
                Value = from i in p.Value.Items
                        select new ListViewItem
                                {
                                    Token = i.Token,
                                    IsFatalError = i.IsFatal,
                                    Checked = false,
                                    Line = i.Token.Position.Line,
                                    Description = i.Description,
                                    BackgroundBrush = i.IsFatal 
                                                        ? Brushes.Red 
                                                        : null
                                }
            }
    ).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks! how do I transform it to query form ?

Comment: There's no `ToDictionary` in the query form. You could transform the `p.Value.Items.Select()` to a query, but I think there's no reason for it.

Comment: As far as I know, `ToDictionary` cannot be expressed in query form. The best you can do is convert as much to query form as possible and then apply `ToDictionary` on it.

Comment: @w0lf - yes, exactly - as much query form, all surrounded with parenthesis and `ToDictionay(?)`, like: `(/*...query...*/).ToDictionary(/*what's here?*/)`

Comment: @Tal please see the update to my answer. Basically, in the `ToDictionary` call on an `IEnumerable<T>` you have to provide two `Func`s: one that will tell it how to get the key from a `T`, and another that will tell it how to get the value.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan - why there's no reason to ? query form is slower or there is it something else ?

Comment: @Tal The query form and its equivalent metod form all compile to the same code (actually the query form is transformed to the methods - you can see that in LINQPad for example). I'm mostly concerned about the readability, which in this case I think is better with the methods. I usually use the query form when enumerating multiple different sources or when using `join` statements. But actually In this case I think there may be another nice way to express this with the query form, I'll show it in another answer.

Comment: Ok, my idea of another approach was not good at all, it's not even worth posting as an answer, as it was far less effective AND less readable than w0lf's version (I was thinking about flattening the collections into one collection of [Key, ListViewItem] and then somehow grouping it into Lookup and then dictionary).

Comment: Thanks @HonzaBrestan for all your effort.